# Query regarding output of a simple Thread example

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying to get started with learning threading in Java and here's a simple example that I tried from [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html#concurrency) 
Here's my code :
 A simple main class:

```
    package com.vogella.Thread;

  import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

      public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // We will store the threads so that we can check if they are done
    List<Thread> threads = new ArrayList<Thread>();
    // We will create 500 threads
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        Runnable task = new MyRunnable(10000000L + i);
        Thread worker = new Thread(task);
        // We can set the name of the thread
        worker.setName(String.valueOf(i));
        // Start the thread, never call method run() direct
        worker.start();
        // Remember the thread for later usage
        threads.add(worker);
    }
    int running = 0;

    do {
        running = 0;
        for (Thread thread : threads) {
            if (thread.isAlive()) {
                running++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("We have " + running + " running threads. ");//-A
    } while (running > 0);

}
}
```

and the MyRunnable class is as follows :

```
package com.vogella.Thread;

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
private final long countUntil;

MyRunnable(long countUntil) {
    this.countUntil = countUntil;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    long sum = 0;
    for (long i = 1; i < countUntil; i++) {

        sum += i;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    System.out.println("Test123");
}
```

}
And this is my output

```
  49999995000000
   Test123
   50000005000000
  Test123
  50000015000001
   Test123...
```

However I dont understand why the line marked with **comment A** in Main.java never prints. Any  insight on this would be helpful.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should print. Check you're not missing it in the program output.
Try commenting out the println()'s in your Runnable

Comment: Just ran it here and it output fine

Comment: It worked , just that the time lag is really high and the output is not in the order I expected it to be !

Comment: out of curiosity:Each time, the output and ordering are different, why is that?

Comment: Threads are not guaranteed to execute in any particular order.  The processor basically gets to choose when each thread runs and in which order each thread runs.  As such, each time you run it, the processor is picking different scheduling.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things wrong with that code in terms of best practices.  Unless that site mentions them (too lazy to look), I might consider finding a different tutorial. Also, have you checked the entire output? It's probably printing.  It is not guaranteed to print as the last thing as I am going to guess you're assuming.

Answer (score 0):

It should be able to print something. A few ideas for testing:

- comment the println statements in your runnable - maybe it *gets* printed but you don't see it because there's too much output on the console
- add a `System.println(threads.size())` before the `do` statement to see how many threads have been added (should print 500).
- add a `Thread.sleep(100)` before the `do` statement. Maybe the first thread gets alive *after* the do-while block has finished...

Comment: It worked and I got the o/p, but each time I see a different o/p and ordering, why is that ?

Comment: That's called "multitasking" ;) - Seriously, this is the typical behavior with threads: we do not know how they're scheduled. It's simply not predictable and we always have to keep that in mind, if we work with threads.